# What were the things Arthur was delusional about?

Tags: joker

Towards the ending of *Joker*, we realise that Arthur was delusional about certain things that took place in the movie, or that it was all in Arthur's head.

One such thing is his romance with Sophie.

What were the other things he may have been delusional about?

Comment: Theoretically the entire movie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*start of the enumeration points from answer posted by [papakias](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27722/papakias)*

> 1. Arthur being in a romantic relationship with his neighbour
> 2. His first appearance in the TV show where the presenter (R. DeNiro) hugs him

3. There is also another scene in the movie, which is at least hinted to be an illusion of arthur.

   Arthur stoically empties his fridge at night, climbs in and shuts the door. 
   The scene fades out and is cut the a day-lit scene showing the fridge from a similar angle, without any of the contents on the ground, the camera then pans to show Arthur lying on his bed.

   Of course it can be argued, that he climbed out of the fridge, restored its contents and then went sleeping, but it could also be a simple dream or delusion.

   *[Psychonaut](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/19812/psychonaut) argues: The fridge he gets into is an old-style one that closes with a mechanical latch, not a magnetic seal like modern appliances. There's generally no way of opening those old fridges from the inside.*
4. Additionally it seems that he is firing a few more bullets than he should be having in his barrel when dealing with the guys in the first train scene.
   He does not seem to be in a reloading-mood in the scene. So it is either a (deliberate) mistake or something that Arthur did not seem to care about in his delusion.

Comment: No, I don't think it can be argued that Arthur climbed back out of the fridge.  The fridge he gets into is an old-style one that closes with a mechanical latch, not a magnetic seal like modern appliances.  There's generally no way of opening those old fridges from the inside.  This physically impossible scene provides the viewers with a very strong clue that much of what happens on-screen comes from Arthur's unreliable memory.

Comment: @Psychonaut that is a good information. i didnt notice the mechanical latch on the fridge. I have added your input to my answer.

Comment: 5. Your numbering system seems weird.

Comment: @CjDennis check out papakias answer, then you'll understand.;)

Comment: 7. What happens if the other answer is deleted?

Answer (score 9):

I think that the movie is designed in such a way to make you wonder so you will not get a definite answer for this.

Surely 2 things were delusional:

1. Arthur being in a romantic relationship with his neighbour
2. His first appearance in the TV show where the presenter (R. DeNiro) hugs him

The rest seem to be open to the viewer.

Answer (score 3):

Except for the obvious ones which are revealed directly in the movie (His girlfriend and the first TV-Interview) almost everything could be an Illusion but it's entirely up to the viewer!

Maybe Todd Phillips explains it in the future...